# Ruby on Rails User Encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I've completed several tutorials of different length and difficulty, a few of them building a custom authentication system from scratch. Most times I seem to find the following way of encrypting the password.

`rails generate model User name:string email:string`

and then

`rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string`

Which produces a hashed password the the development database, when viewed, instead of the password (password1) it shows something like RFTER4dr3wxMnei instead.

Is it possible to add other attributes to the user via this method? For example, if I had two authentication methods (enter username and password) then (enter memorable information) could they both be encrypted using the same method?

or how, in theory, (and if possible) could you use it to encrypt all of the user's data (their name, email, date of birth, password etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not encryption, it is crystallographic hashing. A hash function is a function that produces a unique output for every input, from which it is *impossible* (theoretically) to reconstruct the input (short of a brute force attack, or something like a hash table).

Hash functions are perfect for authentication, because it means that you are *not actually storing the password*. You only store something the you can confirm the correctness of the password with. Every time someone logs in, the password given is hashed using the same algorithm, and the hashes are compared. This way, if someone breaks into your database, they can't actually get the passwords.

Information that you actually need to access, not just verify (you need to verify password, but access DoB, username, etc.) can be *encrypted*, but then you need to figure out how you are dealing with keys and such, because if someone can steal the encrypted information from the same place as the key, it's effectively pointless.

Worth mentioning: while it's great for learning, don't implement your own authentication systems in production unless you have too. Either use some open source code that has been reviewed by security experts, or use third party authentication that is trusted and secure (Log in with Google, OpenID, Oauth, Log in with Facebook, etc.)

Comment: Thank you your answer way very useful. By "how you are dealing with keys" I'm not 100% sure what you mean? I think I might be able to give an explanation. I'm using key value pairs and have two hashed variables in my database, the **password digest** and **remember token** as an example here is the password digest and remember token for an example user in my database. Digest: **$2a$10$ZUg8kc8KEELrRZnEtXQLZewVlkGZ9p1LguRvAYrX.iLRJXL8aKCY** and Token **PwcKkFsI3xJVevx-iDzWPg** Is that similar to what you were talking about?

Comment: @Aluxzi: No. I'm talking about encryption keys. It's a big concept, and you should probably Google for some better explanations than those I can give.